# ProcessPoolExecutor and ray

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ray

I have written some code that follows the following structure. Basically I am accessing some files from the disk and I am doing some image processing operations on them.

The program below makes a pool of processes and within each process a pool of threads. The threads read the files and then do the operation.

I have done a ray cluster and I want to run this code on my cluster. I havent quite understood how I should change it please? Im a complete beginner with ray.

I believe there is no need for an Actor here, right? I should probably make a task, could you please help me how to do that?

Thanks!

```
import os
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def spawn_threads(items):
    with ThreadPool() as pool:
        out = pool.map(img_job, items)
        return out


def img_job(item):
    """
    some image enhancing operation takes place in the GPU here
    """


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def preprocess(self, n_workers=1):
        files = [os.path.join(self.path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(self.path)]
        chunksize = max(1, round(len(files) / n_workers))
        # create the process pool
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(n_workers) as executor:
            futures = []
            # split into chunks
            for i in range(0, len(files), chunksize):
                # select a chunk of filenames
                chunk = files[i:(i + chunksize)]
                out = spawn_threads(chunk)
        return out
```